# Why is not working with no args input in java

Tags: java, args

I wanted to write wc program in java so wrote this code
It works well when I write the command in cmd but when I don't write anything for args it should be work for all of them but it wouldn't work and give me an Exception with args[0].equal ... .
Thank you for your helps!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int linesNumber = 0;
        int wordsNumber = 0;
        int charsNumber = 0;
        String line;
        String word;
        while (!(line = scan.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
            linesNumber++;
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(line); //reading lines
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                word = reader.next();
                wordsNumber++;
                charsNumber += word.length();
            }
        }
        if(args[0].isEmpty()){
            System.out.print(linesNumber +" " +wordsNumber +" " +charsNumber);
        }else if(args[0].equals("-l") || args[0].equals("--lines")){
            System.out.println(linesNumber);
        }else if(args[0].equals("-w") || args[0].equals("--words")){
            System.out.println(wordsNumber);
        }else if(args[0].equals("-c") || args[0].equals("--chars")){
            System.out.println(charsNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Berger No, `args[0]` is not `null`, it simply doesn't exist because size of array is `0` so there is no first element (indexed by 0). OP need to check for array length, not for `null`.

Comment: @Pshemo : Indeed , removed the incorrect comment .

Comment: @OP When there are no arguments provided then `args` array is simply empty like 

    `String[] args = {};`

so there are *no elements* in there, not even first one (indexed as 0). 

Before trying to access element at specified index (like `[0]`), you need to make sure that such element exist. Valid indexes are in range `0`..`length-1`, otherwise you will see exception about incorrect bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that where you have

```
if(args[0].isEmpty())
```

you mean

```
if (args.length==0)
```

If you pass no arguments to the program, `args` will be an empty array, so trying to access `args[0]` at all will raise an exception.